# Add a column to any position in a file in unix [using awk or sed]

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk

I'm looking for other alternatives/more intelligent 1 liner for following command, which should add a value to a requested column number.
I tried following following sed command works properly for adding value 4 to the 4th column.
[Need: As i have such file which contains 1000 records & many times i need to add a column in between at any position.]
My approch is sutaible for smaller scale only.

`cat 1.txt`

```
1|2|3|5
1|2|3|5
1|2|3|5
1|2|3|5
```

`sed -i 's/1|2|3|/1|2|3|4|/g' 1.txt`

`cat 1.txt`

```
1|2|3|4|5
1|2|3|4|5
1|2|3|4|5
1|2|3|4|5
```

thansk in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Field Separators**
http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Separators.html

**String Concatenation**
http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Concatenation.html

**Default pattern and action**
http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Very-Simple.html

```
 awk -v FS='|' -v OFS='|' '{$3=$3"|"4} 1' 1.txt
```

Answer (score 7):

One way using `awk`. Pass two arguments to the script, the column number and the value to insert. The script increments the number of fields (`NF`) and goes throught the last one until the indicated position and insert there the new value.

Run this command:

```
awk -v column=4 -v value="four" '
    BEGIN {
        FS = OFS = "|";
    }
    {
        for ( i = NF + 1; i > column; i-- ) {
            $i = $(i-1);
        }
        $i = value;
        print $0;
    }
' 1.txt
```

With following output:

```
1|2|3|four|5
1|2|3|four|5
1|2|3|four|5
1|2|3|four|5
```

Answer (score 2):

One way using `coreutils` and process substitution:

```bash
f=1.txt
paste -d'|'                       \
  <(cut -d'|' -f1-3 $f          ) \
  <(yes  4 | head -n`wc -l < $f`) \
  <(cut -d'|' -f4- $f           )
```

Answer (score 1):

One way, using coreutils and process substitution:

```
sed 's/3|/3|4|/' 1.txt
```

Comment: Actually there's no process substitution in this answer. Looks like you copied that header from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11628164/56541), possibly without understanding it. (Is `sed` a coreutil anyway?)